# Using FileReader, how can I read the next line of a list of #'s, and then multiply it by another value?

Tags: java

Say I have a file called `AnnualRateOfReturn.txt` with a list of numbers for each line. Lets call that variable X. The numbers read from the file will be percentages.

In a loop, I want to take one variable, lets say Y, and then multiply it by 1.X value read from the **first** line AnnualRateOfReturn.

After it loops again, I want it to take a new value, read from the **next line** of the file AnnualRateOfReturn.txt, and then multiply the Y value by the new 1.X variable.

For each loop, it should read the next line and then multiply the Y variable by that value.

**Example:**

AnnualRateOfReturn.txt

```
Line1: 0.04
Line2: 0.24
```

On the first loop, the Y value should be multiplied by 1.04
On the second loop, the next line should be read, and the Y value should be multiplied by 1.24

I need to accomplish this with the FileReader class.

Answer (score 1):

```
//create a Scanner to scan through the file that FileReader reads
//note: must deal with FileNotFoundException 
//which will be thrown if FileReader(source) cannot find the source file
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("path/to/AnnualRateOfReturn.txt"));
//scanner.hasNext() ensures that the scanner has a token to read
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    //create your x value, this will throw an exception if the next token isn't a Double
    double x = 1 + scanner.nextDouble();
    //do your math
    y = y*x;
}
```

Comment: if you want to put this whole section into a method then no not really (other than making it `return y`), you can make some improvements, firstly make the file name a mthod parameter then make the method throw the filenotfoundexception so the signature would look like `public static double annualRates(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException`. Thats all just preference though

Comment: Sorry if this seems obvious, I'm still really new to java. Where am I going wrong in my method? http://pastebin.com/MTB90BKr

Comment: `x` only exists within the scope of the while loop (it is also getting re-set every iteration so it will never compund). if you want to return x you need to declare it outside of the `while` loop. however im not quite sure thats what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use Scanner to read the file

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("C:\\PATH_TO_THE_FILE\\AnnualRateOfReturn.txt");
```

now to read a line :

```
String line= sc.nextLine();
```

to get the value :

```
double x=1 + Double.valueOf(line);
```

if you want to test if file still has lines use :

```
while(sc.hasNext())
```

and then do the math ... good luck

Comment: Will not work, `sc` in your example will read through the `String` you gave it

Comment: no it would read the nextline in the file and put it inside line

Comment: No it wont, read the documentation or even try the method out. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String) `new Scanner(String source)` will scan the literal `String` `source` not a file it points to

Comment: thought u were talking about variable line ... yeah its (new File("..")) .. oops